# Object.is (SameValueZero) potencial bug

Tags: javascript, v8

I have faced the following unexpected results (latest Chrome, FF):

```
var o = {foo: "bar"};
alert(Object.is(o, {foo: "bar"})); //false

var map = new Map();
map.set(o, 1);

var o2 = {foo: "bar"};
alert(map.get(o2)); //undefined
```

I'm having problems with retrieving values from Maps because of such behavior. Any way to fix that without serious performance losses?

Thanks

Comment: Two different objects are never equal to each other. This is not a bug, this the specified behavior. See lots of related questions (potential duplicates): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+map+object+key+equality+ .

Comment: Found more on my issue: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html
The question might be closed as well...

Answer (score 0):

Given example objects at Question you can use `JSON.stringify()` to compare `JSON` format representation of objects.

Note, the approach should not be used as a general solution.

```js
var o = {foo: "bar"};

console.log(JSON.stringify(o) === JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"}));
```

Comment: But is it guaranteed that they will always have everything in the same order? I think not.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can you share an example of what you are describing?

Comment: That only works for certain types of value, e.g. `JSON.stringify(function(){}) == JSON.stringify(function(){return 2});` returns `true` when clearly the functions are not equivalent.

Comment: @RobG Yes. Noted the same at Answer. That is, given example objects at Question.

Comment: @guest271314—fine, but I think it's worth clearly stating that this isn't a general solution.

Comment: @RobG `.toString()` can be used to get expected result where function is passed as parameter `JSON.stringify()` `JSON.stringify(function(){}.toString()) == JSON.stringify(function(){return 2}.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like I found a solution. I'm gonna have to stringify keys and use regular objects a-like:

```
var map = new Map();

var o = {foo: "bar"};
map.set(o, "val");

//---->

var map = {};

var k = JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"});
map[k] = "val";
```

Comment: it's ok. but in theory, the object `{a: 0, b: 1}` can be stringified to `{"b": 1, "a": 0}` because objects has no sequence or iterator inside. and there is no any specification says about a right sequence. so checking the equality by stringified objects is on you own risk

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { key: 'val' };
```

in the above statement because the actual value that will be store by `obj` is not object itself and it is object reference, `Object.is` and `Map.set/get` functions and even `===` operator compare object reference and not the value.

So `obj === { key: 'val' }` and `Object.is(o, { key: 'val' })` are absolutely false;

[Read more about object references](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0).